# In Vue.js, how can I retrieve json data from a ThingSpeak API and use the coordinates in a Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a Vue JS application. I've installed the [vue-google-maps](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps) package.

Additionally, I've got a GPS tracker that has been configured to send data to the ThingSpeak API.

What I want to do is to get the last coordinate in the API and display it on the Google Map.

My **components\GoogleMap.vue** uses this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap
      :options="{
          center: center,
          zoomControl: true,
          streetViewControl: false,
          clickableIcons: false,
          zoom: zoom,
          gestureHandling: 'auto',
          mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
      }"
      style="width:100%;  height: 500px;"
    >
      <GmapMarker
        :key="index"
        v-for="(m, index) in markers"
        :position="m.position"
        :clickable="true"
        :draggable="false"
        @click="center=m.position"
      ></GmapMarker>
    </GmapMap>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'GoogleMap',
  data () {
    return {
      // just a dummy location for now: Accra, in Ghana
      // change this to get the API location from ThingSpeak
      // this center is exported to the template
      center: { lat: 5.5912045, lng: -0.2497708 },
      zoom: 13,
      markers: [{
        position: { lat: 5.5912045, lng: -0.2497708 }
      }]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, this is my **src\main.js**:

(I've taken out my API key for security purposes)

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: <API_KEY_GOES_HERE>
  },
  installComponents: true
})

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

When I run this, the map correctly displays on my webpage. However, I don't know to get the coordinates from the ThingSpeak API, rather than directly hard-coding it!

I'm new to Vue...

I was able to do this in regular JS, but I can't seem to do it in Vue...

Here's what I did:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Experiment</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




    <script>
      // Initialize global variables



      // Initialize and add the map
      function initMap() {
        // get the last location sent 

        // get LATITUDE
        $.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/<CHANNEL_ID>/fields/1/last.json?api_key=<THINGSPEAK_READ_API_KEY>", function(result){

          var m = result;
          // set latitude as x
          x=Number(m.field1);

        });

        // get LONGITUDE
        $.getJSON("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/<CHANNEL_ID>/fields/2/last.json?api_key=<THINGSPEAK_READ_API_KEY>", function(result){

          var m = result;
          // set longitude as y
          y=Number(m.field2);

        }).done(function (){

          coordinates = {lat: x, lng: y};


          // The map, centered at the location given
          var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 13, center: coordinates});
          // The marker, positioned at the location given
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: coordinates, 
            map: map,
            title: 'Click to get coordinates'
          });

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: '<p>Tracker Location: ' + marker.getPosition() + '</p>'
          });

          map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
            // 3 seconds after the center of the map has changed, pan back to the
            // marker.
            window.setTimeout(function() {
              map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            }, 5000);
          });

          marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            // when the marker is clicked, center map
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
          });
        });





      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<API_KEY_GOES_HERE>&callback=initMap"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

So basically, I'm just trying to redo this, but in Vue. Thanks...

Comment: From the top, you would have to understand what vue lifecycle [https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/] is all about, you would need to control events between the created and mounted hooks. If you can fetch the data from the api in your created cycle using fetch or axios, you can use the values to build your map properties before mounted is completed. I think you are 3 readings away from doing this.

Comment: A sandbox like this can go on to guide you https://repl.it/repls/GrippingLightgreyHashfunction